# How do I conditionally add modules using 'if' statement and 'require"?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to conditionally load a module I made with an 'if' statement in Node.js, but it keeps coming back undefined.

```
// Module1 and module2 load fine
const module1 = require("aModule");
const module2 = require("anotherModule");

// Running function that returns module3's file path
let myModuleLocation = isMyModuleHere();
// Returns file path './module/mymodule.js'

// Defining module3
if (myModuleLocation !== null) {
    const module3 = require('myModuleLocation');
}
let myModuleData = module3.doStuff(stuff);
// Returns error when run in terminal: module3 is not defined
```

However, this works just fine:

```
let myModuleLocation = isMyModuleHere();
const module3 = require('myModuleLocation');
let myModuleData = module3.doStuff(stuff);
```

What is happening and how can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Constants are block-scoped. Your module3 is defined inside of the if block and would not be accessible outside it.

Comment: Have you tried declaring module3 above the  conditional statement like let module3; then assign it inside the conditional.  let module3; if(myModuleLocation !== null) {module3 = require('myModuleLocation');}

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Declare module3 and myModuleData outside of the if block using let keyword and assign values inside the if block.

```
// Module1 and module2 load fine
const module1 = require("aModule");
const module2 = require("anotherModule");

// Running function that returns module3's file path
let myModuleLocation = isMyModuleHere();
// Returns file path './module/mymodule.js'

// Defining module3
let module3; 
let myModuleData;
if (myModuleLocation) {
    module3 = require(`${myModuleLocation}`);
    myModuleData = module3.doStuff(stuff);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did something like this and it worked. I got so caught up looking through documentation on 'require' I temporarily forgot that block scope was a thing.

Comment: @Teatree Happens to all of us. Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string not the path returned to your require also declare the variable using the keyword `var` so that you will be able to use it outside the if statement, since let and const are block scoped

```
myModuleLocation = isMyModuleHere();
if (myModuleLocation !== null) {
    var module3 = require('myModuleLocation');<---- that's a string 
}
```

Change it to this

```
const module3 = require(`${myModuleLocation}`)
```